# Design navigation using CSS

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to develop navigation bar using CSS.
I am display menus in navigation but these menus are not displaying as expected. I am trying to display as below.

[image]

```css
 ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
         
        }

        li a {
                display: block;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
            
        }

       li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
            border-top: 4px solid #2e92fa;
        }
```

```html
   <ul>
        <li><a class="active" >Product Name</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" >Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a >Reports</a></li>
        <li><a >Map</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Can someone help me to change css classes in order to look like as below image? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: add border-top on hover .. as simple as that

Comment: but what exactly do you want? borders, font, that active mark in blue?

Comment: if you want blue border on top than try this in your css
`li a:hover { background-color: #111;
border-top:2px solid blue;}`

Comment: Thanks, Border on click i need(dark) and on hover light border i need.

Comment: li a:hover {
                    border-color: #111;
        }
li a.active {
                    border-color: #000; border-top:5px solid blue;
        }

Comment: Thanx Uzair. I added but whenever i do hover,menu is coming down. It is moving down side.

Comment: li a {
            
            border-top: 4px solid transparent;
        }
will keep away jerk

Comment: Also How can i add red line above the product name?

Comment: @Niranjan do you want the red line on mouse over or any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that the way you want it to be ?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px 20px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #222;
  border-top: 6px solid #2e92fa;
}

li a:active {
  background-color: #000;
  border-top: 6px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a>Reports</a></li>
  <li><a>Map</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works fine except whenever i click on any menu    border-top: 4px solid #2e92fa; should be very dark. If i  keep mouse then    border-top: 4px solid #2e92fa; little dark i want to make top border.

Comment: @Niranjan, I edited my answer but I am not sure about the way you want it. Anyway, if the functionnality is good for you, you can modify the colors the way you want it to be, right?

Comment: Thanks it is working. May I know how can i add red bar as i shown in the image above?

Comment: The “Product name” isn't in your html code. How do you want it to be added ? And when do you want the red border to appear ?

Comment: Yeah correct but i want to add that to my html code. May i know  where can i add these?

Answer (score 2):

You can use psuedo classes for this
:active works on click
:hover works on mouse over

```
ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;

        }

        li a {
                display: block;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                border-top: 4px solid transparent;

        }

       li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
            border-top: 4px solid #2e92fa;
        }

        li a:active
        {
            border-top:4px solid blue;
        }
 <ul>
        <li><a class="active" >Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a >Reports</a></li>
        <li><a >Map</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, But how can i add red bar above the product name?

Comment: How do you want it on mouse over??

Comment: If you find it useful mark it as the correct answer